# HTML 5 File Reader Sync

Tags: html, web-worker, html5-filesystem

I am using web workers and the file system api to read the contents of files. However, whenever I try to read the file I get a DOM EXCEPTION 8 : NOT FOUND ERROR on the line of code that is var message = read.readAsText(fileEntry); Can anyone help explain why this is occurring?

```
path = e.data + "/" + "index.html";

var buffers = [];

var message = "";

var fileEntry = fs.root.getFile(path, {create: false});

var reader = new FileReaderSync();
message = reader.readAsText(fileEntry);

self.postMessage(message);
```

Comment: Are you certain the file exists? MDN states that error is " raised when the resource represented by the DOM Blob or File cannot be found, e. g. because it has been erased".

Comment: Yes I am sure that the file exists. Even when I change the getFile to create true I still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

readAsText requires a File object, not a [FileEntrySync](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileEntrySync#File) object. Call fileEntry.file() to get the File object.

```
path = e.data + "/" + "index.html";
var buffers = [];
var message = "";
var fileEntry = fs.root.getFile(path, {create: false});
var reader = new FileReaderSync();
```

`message = reader.readAsText(fileEntry.file());`

```
self.postMessage(message);
```